# Sendmail Message Fail

Tags: rhel, sendmail

On my Redhat Prod Server I installed Sendmail that I will use to send DB Backup completion mails to my email id.

When I send a email from My Server A 172.16.233.2 to my email id abc@domain.com. using

sendmail -v myemailid@domain.com < /opt/dailydbscriptoutput.txt

```
myemailid@domain.com... Connecting to [127.0.0.1] via relay...
220 db.erp.com ESMTP Sendmail 8.13.8/8.13.8; Thu, 7 Aug 2014 13:37:17 +0300
>>> EHLO pmmcdb.erp.com
250-db.erp.com Hello localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1], pleased to meet you
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE
250-DSN
250-ETRN
250-DELIVERBY
250 HELP
>>> MAIL From:<emerg@db.erp.com> SIZE=59
250 2.1.0 <emerg@db.erp.com>... Sender ok
>>> RCPT To:<myemailid@domain.com>
>>> DATA
250 2.1.5 <myemailid@domain.com>... Recipient ok
354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself
>>> .
250 2.0.0 s77AbH2H025298 Message accepted for delivery
myemailid@domain.com... Sent (s77AbH2H025298 Message accepted for delivery)
Closing connection to [127.0.0.1]
>>> QUIT
221 2.0.0 db.erp.com closing connection
```

I get the above message. But when I check the Log /var/log/maillog. I See this

```
Aug  7 12:18:41db sendmail[11808]: s779If28011808: from=emerg, size=59, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201408070918.s779If28011808@db.erp.com>, relay=emerg@localhost
Aug  7 12:18:41 db sendmail[11809]: s779Ifss011809: from=<emerg@db.erp.com>, size=342, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201408070918.s779If28011808@db.erp.com>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1]
Aug  7 12:18:41 db sendmail[11808]: s779If28011808: to=myemailid@domain.com, ctladdr=emerg (503/503), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30059, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (s779Ifss011809 Message accepted for delivery)
Aug  7 12:18:42 db sendmail[11811]: s779Ifss011809: to=<myemailid@domain.com>, ctladdr=<emerg@db.erp.com> (503/503), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=relay, pri=120342, relay=mail1 [10.171.1.10], **dsn=5.6.0, stat=Data format error**
```

Previously I was facing issue on server related to DNS.

**Name server timeout**

So I followed this Link [Setup Sendmail without DNS](http://devnull.crapules.com/2008/04/04/setup-sendmail-without-dns) to solve the issue and on another Test server it started working and then I applied the same procedure on this Production server and im not able to send messages

## After Testing

```
sendmail -Am -v myemailid@domain.com  < /tmp/email.txt
myemailid@domain.com... Connecting to mail1 via relay...
220 mail1.etradeportal.net ESMTP Sendmail 8.13.1/8.13.1; Thu, 7 Aug 2014 15:18:51 +0300
>>> EHLO db.erp.com
250-mail1.etradeportal.net Hello [172.16.233.2], pleased to meet you
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE
250-DSN
250-ETRN
250-AUTH DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5
250-DELIVERBY
250 HELP
>>> MAIL From:<root@db.erp.com> SIZE=108
553 5.1.8 <root@db.erp.com>... Domain of sender address root@db.erp.com does not exist
/root/dead.letter... Saved message in /root/dead.letter
Closing connection to mail1
>>> QUIT
221 2.0.0 mail1.etradeportal.net closing connection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the script below:

```
#!/bin/sh
FILE=/opt/dailydbscriptoutput.txt 
TO=myemailid@domain.com 

(cat - $FILE <<END) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -i $TO
TO: $TO

END
```

Sendmail expects headers and body separated by an empty line in "raw" format.

To get better debug info execute the above script as root with `-Am -v` command line options passed to sendmail.

---

Fixing `Domain of sender address root@db.erp.com does not exist`

On the receiving host add `db.erp.com` entry to `/etc/hosts` file [db.erp.com uses private/"non public"/"intranet only" IP address]

Comment: I added the Debug of "sudo myemailid@domain.com  < /tmp/email.txt" its throwing Domain of Sender Address not found.

Comment: I added the entry on receiving Server's /etc/hosts file. But still same issue. Although another server is working with same conig but I didnt mention that server's IP or hostname on receiving server's Hosts file still that server is working. But this Prod server is not working even with same configs

Comment: Ok I fixed the issue. I used the complete IP, FQDN and SHORTNAME of DB Server and insert in the Mail Relay Server's host file and vice versa and this damn thing start working.